# Cannot login to LinkedIn in JavaFX WebView

Tags: java, webview, linkedin-api, javafx-webengine, torii

I'm integrating a website into an existing Java application, which is using JavaFX WebView. Unfortunately login with LinkedIn in the website is broken.

I'm using [Torii](https://github.com/Vestorly/torii) to handle the login, which opens a popup window, where the user logs in to LinkedIn. It works for normal browsers but in the JavaFX WebView it fails - after the login I end up in an error page by LinkedIn that says

> **Request Error**,  We’re sorry, there was a problem with your
>   request. Please make sure you have cookies enabled and try again.

The Webview *does* support cookies, so that is *not* the issue.
I suspect the issue is the popup attempts to communicate to the window `opener`, and fails under Java.

Do you have any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Look at your call. Some websites doesn't allow to frame(show) site in other site. You have send frame-option as linkedin requsted.

For example just an iframe;

```
<iframe src="https://www.linkedin.com/"></iframe>
```

When we run index.html console.log show that error;

> Refused to display 'https://www.linkedin.com/' in a frame because it
>   set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

I don't know is there any option for webView setMultipleDisplay() or setFrameOption etc. ;. You have to find that function.